# How to make Safari 4's location bar intelligent like Firefox 3?

Tags: mac, firefox, browser, safari

My favorite feature of Firefox 3 is its incredible location bar. Type a few letters of any bookmark name or url or the title of any page you've visited recently or its url and it will work some query magic and show you relevant results.

It's the main reason I use Firefox 3 instead of Safari 4 for everyday browsing. I would like to use Safari instead because it is so much faster, especially since I run a ton of Firefox 3 extensions for development.

I'd like to use Firefox 3 for development only, and Safari for everything else.

But Safari's location bar is so disappointing. Simple example: I have a bookmark called GD. If I type GD into the location bar, it suggests no results.

Considering Webkit is open source it would be AWESOME if someone took some code from Firefox and threw it into Webkit to make the location bar useful.

Or is there some plugin that already does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that while WebKit is open source, Safari is not open source, so adding this functionality to Safari is not quite as easy as you may believe.

You could consider that someone already took the WebKit engine and added the intelligent location bar to WebKit. They just named it Google Chrome.

Comment: Sadly, Chrome isn't really available yet for the Mac.  There are dev builds, but it's not release quality yet.

Comment: You can get the beta version now at google.com/chrome

Comment: 3 months later, yup.